# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587 Can not manage to solve this problem

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send an email in Android Studio without intents and to achieve this I'm trying to use the JavaMail API. However I got an error every time I tried to send an email:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587

I have already implemented `activation.jar`, `additional.jar` and `mail.jar` to my project. Also, I gave permission in the Manifest file for INTERNET. I also gave permission for lower security access on my Gmail account.

Here's my code:

public class MailSend extends AsyncTask {

```
//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;

//Information to send email
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;

//Progressdialog to show while sending email
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//Class Constructor
public MailSend(Context context, String email, String subject, String message) {
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //Showing progress dialog while sending email
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Sending message", "Please wait...", false, false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Dismissing the progress dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //Showing a success message
    Toast.makeText(context, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    final String username = "user";
    final String password = "pass";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pass");
                }
            });

    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user"));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding message
        mm.setText(message);

        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Could anyone please tell me if my code is wrong or am I missing something? Here's the full error output.

```html
W/System.err: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
                nested exception is:
W/System.err:  java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/64.233.184.108 (port 465) from /:: (port 56438): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
                  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
                  at com.example.meric.knockknockapp.MailSend.doInBackground(MailSend.java:105)
                  at com.example.meric.knockknockapp.MailSend.doInBackground(MailSend.java:31)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/64.233.184.108 (port 465) from /:: (port 56438): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:138)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:565)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
                  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
               ... 14 more
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
                  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:126)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:152)
                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
```

Comment: Please show us the complete stacktrace

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I have posted above works completely fine. The issue was that I was on a public network, which seems to cause of the problem. When I switch to a private network the problem is gone.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Change Properties to this:-

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465")
```

If didn't work

Check this Link:-[Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608089/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-587-nested-exception-is)

Hope this will Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for me:-

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;
//Information to send email
private String email="", femail="", fpass="";
private String subject="";
private String message="";

//Class Constructor
public SendMail(Context context, String fromemail, String frompass, String toemail, String subject, String message) {
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = toemail;
    this.femail = fromemail;
    this.fpass = frompass;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Showing a success message
    Toast.makeText(context, "Send to "+email+" from "+femail+".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Creating properties
    Properties props = new Properties();

    //Configuring properties for gmail
    //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(femail, fpass);
                }
            });
    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);
        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(femail));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding message
        mm.setText(message);           
        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}