# Send mail through web application

Tags: java, email, jsf

I am using the following properties to send mail through web application that use jsf but I am getting an error

The properties:

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");    
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");    
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");   
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        return new PasswordAuthentication("email@gmail.com", "password");

    }
```

The error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608089/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-587-nested-exception-is)

Comment: no i have different problem

Comment: Don't forget to check your firewall. Firewall sometimes prevents from sending email.

Comment: I disabled it but it still giving me this

Comment: Your system cannot resolve the DNS address for smtp.gmail.com, which means you're either not connected to the internet, or you're behind a proxy and your local DNS settings (or DNS server) don't route to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try these on command line.

For SSL:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

For TLS/STARTTLS:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

If there's no response its a firewall issue.

Comment: I got a response