# Could not convert socket to TLS Spring Mail

Tags: spring-boot, email, gmail

**I am getting the errors:**
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: **Could not convert socket to TLS**;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: **No appropriate protocol** (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
Email sender service class:

```
@Service
public class EmailSenderService {
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void sendEmail(String toEmail,
                      String subject,
                      String body){
    SimpleMailMessage message=new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setFrom("group18proj@gmail.com");
    message.setTo(toEmail);
    message.setText(body);
    message.setSubject(subject);

    mailSender.send(message);

    System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully...");
}
```

Mail Controller:

```
    @Autowired
EmailSenderService emailSenderService;

@RequestMapping("/mail")
public String sendMail(HttpSession session, Model model){
    emailSenderService.sendEmail("mrleftgamer@gmail.com","Test","This is the body of the test email");
    session.setAttribute("mailMessage", "Check your email");
    return "redirect:/dashboard";
}
```

Comment: Try to add spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true in application.property file

Comment: @Nemanja I am now getting this error "Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587"

Comment: Did you allowed less secure applications to access this gmail account group18proj@gmail.com? If not, you need to enable it. beacause it's disabled by default

Comment: @Nemanja I am getting the same error

Comment: Your code is fine, but for some reason host that you are trying to connect to is not reachable.  Checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608089/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-587-nested-exception-is

Comment: @Nemanja Unfortunately I have tried all the problems but I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem today. My antivirus was at fault. After temporarily disabling Avast the mail sender worked as expected.